# node.js usb InEndpoint Error under Ubuntu 12.04 Arm 7 Cortex

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, usb, arm, armv7

I have trouble on my current target hardware (utilite standard) which has an ARMv7 internally. When using node.js with the usb module it works well under my pc where I developed it but now there are problems when porting it to the target when reading the device with the transmit-method of the usb module.

here are some details of the system:

```
Linux utilite-ubuntu-desktop 3.0.35-cm-fx6-4 #123 SMP Thu Sep 12 10:41:30 IST 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
libusb version: 1.0-9 or 1.0-18 (both tested)
node.js version: 0.10.22 (highest 0.10.x version to run on the target)
usb version: latest, (but also others tested downto 2.0)
```

The Errors I get are the following (in this order):

```
{ [Error: **UNKNOWN**] errno: 6 }
```

or

```
{ [Error: **UNKNOWN**] errno: 2 }
```

I looked up the error numbers which seem to come directly from libusb (errno.h):

```
#define ENOFILE 2   /* No such file or directory */
#define ENOENT  2
#define ENXIO   6   /* No such device or address */
```

My applications source code is:

```
var usb = require('usb');

var panel_on_USB = usb.findByIds(conf.USB_VID, conf.USB_PID);
panel_on_USB.open();

console.log("interface :");
console.log(panel_on_USB.interface(0));
console.log("timeout :" + panel_on_USB.timeout);

var panel_interface = panel_on_USB.interface(0);
panel_interface.claim();

console.log("isKernelDriverActive: " + panel_interface.isKernelDriverActive());
console.log("descriptor: " + panel_interface.descriptor);
console.log("panel_interface: " + panel_interface.endpoints);
console.log("LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN = " + usb.LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN);
console.log("LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT = " + usb.LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT);
console.log(panel_interface.endpoint(1).direction);
console.log(panel_interface.endpoint(2).direction);
console.log(panel_interface.endpoint(131).direction);
console.log(panel_interface.endpoint(132).direction);
```

Outputs to the console:

```
interface :
{ device:
   { busNumber: 2,
     deviceAddress: 3,
     deviceDescriptor:
      { bLength: 18,
        bDescriptorType: 1,
        bcdUSB: 512,
        bDeviceClass: 0,
        bDeviceSubClass: 0,
        bDeviceProtocol: 0,
        bMaxPacketSize0: 8,
        idVendor: 1240,
        idProduct: 62765,
        bcdDevice: 0,
        iManufacturer: 1,
        iProduct: 2,
        iSerialNumber: 0,
        bNumConfigurations: 1 },
     interfaces: [ [Circular] ] },
  id: 0,
  altSetting: 0,
  descriptor:
   { bLength: 9,
     bDescriptorType: 4,
     bInterfaceNumber: 0,
     bAlternateSetting: 0,
     bNumEndpoints: 4,
     bInterfaceClass: 255,
     bInterfaceSubClass: 255,
     bInterfaceProtocol: 255,
     iInterface: 0,
     extra: <Buffer >,
     endpoints: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  interfaceNumber: 0,
  endpoints:
   [ { device: [Object],
       descriptor: [Object],
       address: 1,
       transferType: 2 },
     { device: [Object],
       descriptor: [Object],
       address: 2,
       transferType: 2 },
     { device: [Object],
       descriptor: [Object],
       address: 131,
       transferType: 2 },
     { device: [Object],
       descriptor: [Object],
       address: 132,
       transferType: 2 } ] }
timeout :1000
isKernelDriverActive: true
descriptor: [object Object]
panel_interface: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN = 128
LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT = 0
out
out
in
in
```

The transfer call that generates the error:

```
panel_interface.endpoint(131).transfer(Length_Total_Bytes, function(error, data){
            if(error){
                //if(conf.Debug_Console_Output){
                    console.log("USB_receive_Error:");
                    console.log(error);
                //}
            }
//...Data Handling done here...//
});
```

Any Ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occured due to a missmatch of actual recieved data length and set data length in the transfer() method. The following code fixed the problem as always a full buffer is returned to the host by the device (which is wMaxPacketSize) in my case:

```
var In_Transfer_Length = 1 * panel_interface.endpoint(131).descriptor.wMaxPacketSize;
panel_interface.endpoint(131).transfer(In_Transfer_Length, function(error, data){
```

For more details on this see the issue on github:

https://github.com/nonolith/node-usb/issues/45